# Python: decorator/wrapper for try/except statement

Tags: python, try-catch, wrapper, decorator

I have some blocks of code which need to be wrapped by function.

```
try:
    if config.DEVELOPMENT == True:
        # do_some_stuff
except:
    logger.info("Config is not set for development")
```

Then I'll do again:

```
try:
    if config.DEVELOPMENT == True:
        # do_some_another_stuff
except:
    logger.info("Config is not set for development")
```

So, how can I wrap this "do_some_stuff" and "do_some_another_stuff"?

I'm trying to write function with contextmanager:

```
@contextmanager
def try_dev_config(name):
    try:
        if name is not None:
            yield
    except Exception as e:
        print "not dev config"

with try_dev_config("config.DEVELOPMENT"):
    # do_some_stuff
```

And I got an error:

> RuntimeError: generator didn't yield

Comment: You shouldn't compare things against true; it's unnecessarily redundant. Change ` if config.DEVELOPMENT == True` to `if config.DEVELOPMENT`.

Comment: Why pass in a string? Just pass in the value itself: `with try_dev_config(config.DEVELOPMENT):`? Is accessing that attribute the issue?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thx `with try_dev_config(config.DEVELOPMENT):` work's good, but if config.DEVELOPMENT is `False` I got **RuntimeError: generator didn't yield** again.

Comment: Right, yes, a context manager is not the place to conditionally run the block. Don't put the `if` in the context manager, leave that outside.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, so how can I write function which run any block of code if config.DEVELOPMENT == True?

Comment: Why not use functions? Pass in a callback, call it if `config.DEVELOPMENT` is true.

Comment: Because nesting level is too deep: with -- with -- for -- if -- for -- if

Comment: Why are you using a try-except? Does `config.DEVELOPMENT` simply not exist when it isn't set to `True`? If so, you should probably be using the 3-argument form of `getattr` and an `else` block instead of using a try-except.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in a function.

```
boolean = True

def pass_this_in():
    print("I just did some stuff")

def the_try_except_bit(function):
    try:
        if boolean:
            function()
    except:
        print("Excepted")


# Calling the above code
the_try_except_bit(pass_this_in)
```

If you want to reduce the "pass_this_in" definition bit, then you can use [lambda function definitions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk):

```
pass_this_in = lambda : print("I just did some stuff")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that a context manager is the good method to achieve what you want. The context manager goal is to provide a mecanism to open/instantiate a resource, give access to it (or not) and close/clean it automatically when you no more need it.

IMHO, what you need is a [decorator](http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/).
A decorator aims at executing code around a function call. It would force you to put each block of code in a function but I don't think it is so difficult. You can implement it like this:

```
class Config(object):
    """for demonstration purpose only: used to have a config.DEVELOPMENT value"""
    DEVELOPMENT = True

class Logger(object):
    """for demonstration purpose only: used to have a logger.info method"""
    @staticmethod
    def info(msg):
        print("Logged: {}".format(msg))

def check_dev_config(config, logger):
    def dev_config_checker(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                if config.DEVELOPMENT:
                    func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as err:
                logger.info(
                    "Config is not set for developpement: {}".format(err))
        return wrapper
    return dev_config_checker

@check_dev_config(Config, Logger)
def do_stuff_1():
    print("stuff 1 done")

@check_dev_config(Config, Logger)
def do_stuff_2():
    raise Exception("stuff 2 failed")

do_stuff_1()
do_stuff_2()
```

This code prints

```
stuff 1 done
Logged: Config is not set for developpement: stuff 2 failed
```

Explanations:

- The `check_dev_config` function is actually a decorator generator which accepts the `config` and the `logger` as arguments.
- It returns the `dev_config_checker` function which is an actual (and parameterised) decorator, and which accepts a function to decorate as argument.
- This decorator returns a `wrapper` function which will actually run code around the decorated function call. In this function, the decorated function is called inside a `try/except` structure and only if the `config.DEVELOPMENT` is evaluated to True. In case of exception, the `logger` is used to log an information.
- Each block of code to decorate is put into a function (`do_stuff_1`, `do_stuff_2` and decorated with the `check_dev_config` decorator generator, giving it the `config` and the `logger`.
- When decorated functions are called, they are called via their decorator and not directly. As you can see, the `do_stuff_2` exception has been catched and the a message has been logged.